# How do I scan spaces into a a string?

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to scan in 1-3 words from the user into a string. However, Only the first word will scan.

Comment: Post the code of what you are doing.

Comment: Use search facility here. There are number of posts on **scanf** - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scanf

Comment: Which company's scanner are you using ? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scanf("%s", &area ) ;
```

`scanf` stops reading from the stream when a space is encountered. You need to use [getline](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html) instead.

Comment: scanf() is also a huge source of security holes. Not only is getline() more effective, it's also a lot safer.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use a scan set conversion instead of a string conversion:

```
char buffer[256];
scanf("%255[^\n]", buffer);
```

Much like `fgets`, this reads up to the end of the line rather than stopping at the first white-space character.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Actually, scan-sets *are* part of standard C (e.g., §7.19.6.2/12 in C99, §7.9.6.2 in C89/90) -- definitely not the best known part, but there nonetheless.