# reading string with space

Tags: c, scanf

Say for example I have the following main function:

```
int main() 
{

  char a[1023];

  while (scanf("%s",a) != EOF) 
  {
      printf("%s ",a);

  }
}
```

If I input

```
 a ab abc(newline)
```

it should output:

```
 a ab abc(newline)
```

but the main function output

```
 a ab abc (newline) // there is a space between newline and the last string
```

I want to read the string one by one. What is the problem and how can I delete that space? Thank you.

Comment: by `input` do you mean that you're storing a value to `a`, or do you mean command-line arguments?

Comment: With "%s " you are telling printf to put a space there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I scan spaces into a a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853789/how-do-i-scan-spaces-into-a-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `printf("%s ",a);` statement outputs a space after each string it outputs, regardless.  You need to instead output a space only if there are going to be more strings.  Equivalently (and easier), output a space *before* each string if it is not the first:

```
int first = 1;
while (scanf("%s",a) != EOF) {
    if (!first) printf(" ");
    printf("%s",a);
    first = 0;
}
```

also, you never output a newline, despite describing a newline as being output...

Answer (score 1):

A little note about independent learning:

The first time you use *any* standard library function, you should read its corresponding manual at least once. The reason is that as soon as you know about any issues (or helpful features), you'll know to avoid those issues (or use the helpful features). Reading the manual really helps you learn the full potential and avoid the pitfalls of C.

The first time you read something, you may not entirely understand it. Don't let that bother you; Just keep reading. If this happens, I suggest that you read it again once you're at the bottom of the page, and try to understand it completely the second time. Please, read [the fscanf manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) at least once.

---

That's out of the way, now. You might notice little <sup>^</sup> superscripts here and there. My intention is to annotate facts that you would have learnt by reading and understanding the manual I linked to above.

The format specifier `%s` discards as much whitespace as possible prior to attempting to consume as much non-whitespace as possible<sup>^</sup>. Suppose you were to input something with four leading bytes of whitespace, your output wouldn't have those four leading bytes of whitespace.

```
"This    uses    four    spaces" translates to "This uses four spaces".
```

It seems logical that this violates your program specification, which extends your problem<sup>^</sup>. Perhaps you should be using the `%[` format specifier, instead<sup>^</sup>. In that case, an empty line would be considered a match failure and the destination for the line would be indeterminate, so you'd need to handle the return value of `scanf` better<sup>^</sup> (which I encourage you to do, anyway).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char line[512];
    int x;

    do {
        x = scanf("%511[^\n]", line);
        if (x == 0) {
            /* Match failure caused by inputting an empty line. Print empty line? */
            putchar('\n');
        }
        else if (x == 1) {
            /* Success. */
            puts(line);
        }

        /* Read and discard the remainder of a line */
        do { x = getchar(); } while (x >= 0 && x != '\n');
    } while (x != EOF);
}
```

From the length of this loop and the simplicity of the problem, you might reason that using `scanf` for this is probably *the wrong way* to solve the problem. You can eliminate the `line` array, the calls to `scanf` and the resulting `scanf` error checking by using a derivation of the inner-most loop. Something like this looks nice:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c >= 0 && putchar(c) >= 0 && c != '\n');
}
```

PS. There's also a manual for [getchar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getchar.html), [putchar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putchar.html) and [many other standard things](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

Comment: Upvoted for pointing out the manual, but a figurative slap on the wrist for not pointing out most current version. The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7 is here: [The Manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), [`fscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html), [`getchar()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getchar.html), [`putchar()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putchar.html).

Comment: I see you're updated your links to the current version. I unslap you on the figurative wrist. (Also, thank you for having provided the link to the old POSIX documentation, it's useful for comparisons.)

Comment: @ElchononEdelson You may also be interested to note how `fscanf` differs between POSIX and the C standard. In the C standard, `EOF` may only be returned if the end of file is encountered prior to the first successful conversion: *The fscanf function returns the value of the macro `EOF` if an input failure occurs before the ﬁrst conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, the function returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure*. Thankfully, writing code to handle both POSIX and C `fscanf` isn't hard

Comment: `s/end of file/input failure/`

Comment: The wording is different, but I don't see any functional difference between the the C standard and POSIX regarding returning EOF. what am I missing?